# How to fix Pingdom warnings about my DNS configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I just set up my 2 name servers.  I have them on two separate servers I rent.  The primary and secondary DNS for all of my websites work just fine.  I ran a test on Pingdom and received 2 warnings:

**Name Server**
Reverse for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx points to an unknown host name (xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.dedicated.codero.net).
The PTR record for the address points to an unknown host name.

**SOA**
Reverse for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx points to an unknown host name (xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.dedicated.codero.net).
The PTR record for the address points to an unknown host name.

So the same error on both.  The reverse is bound to the static name provided by Codero where I rent my servers.  What should I change on my end to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: You need to speak to Codero and ask them to change the rDNS records for those ip addresses for you.

Comment: TY for the help.  I need them to change the to resolve to NS1.MyNameServer.com and NS2.MyNameServer.com?

Comment: Yes. They need to change the rDNS records to be ns1.yournameserver.com and ns2.yournameserver.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create or change an rDNS record for a specific ip address you need to speak to the party that has administrative control over that rDNS zone. In your case the rDNS zone is handled by Codero, so you need to speak to them about changing the rDNS zone records for those ip addresses to resolve to the FQDN of your name servers.

Comment: TY for the help

Comment: Glad to help...